# is there an easy way to force String.split() to return arrays with empty string elements?

Tags: java, regex, arrays, string, split

in C# I can use the StringSplitOption.None enum element to specify that I want empty strings to be included in the resulting array:

```
String[] s = text.Split(new String[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

In java I can do the following:

```
 String[] s= text.split("\r\n");
```

However, the split method does not return empty strings. (So if text = "a\r\nb\r\n", I want to get {a, b, ""}, rather than {a, b}).

Is there an easy way to accomplish this either via a regex or using some other method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `-1` as your [String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) limit:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("a\r\nb\r\n".split("\\r\\n", -1)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Guava's `Splitter`.  Generally much more logical in terms of how it works.

```
import com.google.common.base.Splitter;
...
System.err.println(Splitter.on("\r\n").split("a\r\nb\r\n"));
```